# Click on spinner element android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, onitemclick

I created a spinner in my main.xml:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/categoria_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/categoria_prompt" />
```

And in the strings.xml the values:

```
<string name="categoria_prompt">Choose</string>
   <string-array name="categoria_arrays">
        <item>All</item>
        <item>One</item>
        <item>Two</item>
        <item>Three</item>
    </string-array>
```

I can display it normally but actually there are no interactions.. I need that onClick over a item open a new activity for example. So if i click the item at position 2 i need go in the activity `One`. Is it possible?

I tried to create a toast when i click a item but not works:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + 
                                   parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //HERE CHANGE ACTIVITY
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
```

I How could i do?

Comment: Try below solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call something like this in your onCreate after your setContentView:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //HERE CHANGE ACTIVITY

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

});
```

Comment: My mistakes, I quickly answered without really checking the syntax, I have edited my anwser, check it out :)

Comment: Prefect, when I arrive home I try :-) but so if I want change activity simply I write ` if (pos == 1){ Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, One.class); startActivity(i); }` for example inside onItemSelected?

Comment: Yes but, be carefull when setting up your listener, the default behavior of Spinner is to fire up a call to OnItemSelected with the default position which is 0 normally. if you don't want it to be called, simply call `spinner.setSelection(mydefaultPosition, false);` before setting your OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Thanks later I try :-)

Comment: Perfect it works!!! Only one thing.. it doesn't display the right "position".. i mean, if i'm in page "One" the spinner is still in "All"..ù

Comment: You have different spinner right ? simply set the wanted position to each spinner before setting the listener. By default it will be at position 0, which in your case I assume is "All"

Comment: mmh, wait there are some things i can't understand at all.. first, the first item at position 0 right now is disabled with `spinner.setSelection(mydefaultPosition, false);`... but if i want call this item from another activity.. How can i do? Second, i don't understand how display the position in the spinner :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47788/discussion-between-gomino-and-end-game)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Do it like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        if (pos == 1){
                Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, One.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }else if (pos == 2)
        {
                Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, Two.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }else if (pos == 3){
                Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, Three.class);
                startActivity(i);
      }
      }
```

and so on...

Comment: I'd also like to add that the first option should do nothing, and for `pos == 1`, `pos == 2` and `pos == 3`, it should start another activity - otherwise if I'm not mistaken, when the activity calls `onCreate`, it will invoke `onItemSelected` and immediately go to the next activity (I think).

Comment: @Trust, Yes first option will not do anything because basically spinner's position starts from 0.

Comment: Right, my bad; I don't know why I thought it'd start from 1.

Comment: Yes this is correct, that's what @Trust try to say that spinner always start it's position from 0 not from 1 so basically this is working code only. Try this one one let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set item selected listener like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the listener for the spinner.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        // your code here
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just added onItemSelected method, or setted onItemSelectListener? onItemSelected and onNothingSelected are just methods, you need to use onItemSelectListener.